# Guaranteed single push of message

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions, rabbitmq

Given:

1. Me as not so seasoned queues user
2. SQL Server table MessagesToPush
3. RabbitMq  exchange to single queue (or multiple - I think it's not important here)
4. c# program which should read from MessagesToPush and send that message to exchange exactly once (if you know some way to enforce on rabbit side - tell me, I might missing something)
5. Algorithm :

   - take a record of not 'sent' state (for simplicity we don't care about concurrency, processing in bulk etc here and later)
   - send/commit to rabbit exchange
   - update row state in DB (set state='sent')
   - repeat

And here some mental block I can't overrun - it's obvious we have a problem if we for example hang between commit to exchange and DB commit. In this scenario we can send our message twice. Yes we can implement checking for doubles on consumer side - but it's quite costly in many respects. So here's my question: is there a good way to ensure **subj**?

Comment: Consumers should be idempotent - i.e. they should always be able to handle the same message coming in twice and end up in the same state, because in many scenarios, that is possible.   Your scenario is rare, but not impossible, so your queue consumer needs to handle it.

Comment: RabbitMQ does not implement transactionality, at all. That's one of the few down sides of it. If you need transactionality, try ActiveMQ or similar.

Comment: Use the "at least once" semantics of RabbitMQ and then use deduplication in the c# program.

Answer (score 1):

**A few thoughts on this:**

First, what you are looking for is called *exactly once delivery*. Nevermind the fact we're not actually dealing with the end consumer - you're referring to delivery to the message broker in your question, so the principles are the same.

**[Exactly once delivery is mathematically impossible](https://bravenewgeek.com/you-cannot-have-exactly-once-delivery/)**.

Why? Consider a case of sending a text to an unreliable friend (we all have them). This particular friend has his message read notifications disabled. You text him to see if he's available for dinner. You wait a few minutes for a reply. He doesn't respond. What happened?

- Did he receive your message and ignore it (as he is prone to do)? If so, maybe he doesn't want to be bothered. Sending another message might annoy him. Do you send your message again anyway?
- Maybe he didn't receive your message, even though the  iPhone indicates it was sent successfully. You had planned on dinner, and if he didn't receive it, now it's going to seem like *you're the one being rude.*

This is an example of **at most once delivery semantics**. Your message may or may not have been delivered, but if it is, it's only going to be delivered once.

**Next**, consider a case where your text message fails to be sent at all. Your phone shows the little (!) icon next to the message. You tap it, then hit the "send again" button. This is an example of **at least once delivery semantics.**  The message may or may not have actually gone through the first time, but your phone indicates an error, and you send again. Unknown to you, two copies of the message were now sent.

**So what?**

In the real world, humans are generally good at handling duplicate information. Thus, for us, at least once delivery is generally acceptable. Humans are usually pretty good at adapting to the realities of unreliable messengers. Unfortunately, you'll never be able to know whether your message was delivered until you find out.

**Bottom line**: if guaranteed delivery is important, design your system around *at least once delivery semantics*.